# What does 'branching' mean in terms of setting/resetting bits?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, branchless

In an interview, I was asked "How do you set or reset a bit?" This is a very simple question, and I answered it.

After that, they asked me how to do the same thing, but without branching. I don't know what branching is.

I search and found [*Bit Twiddling Hacks*](http://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html) by Sean Eron Anderson, but I'm still not getting concept of branching and non-branching.

Please explain 'branching'.

Comment: By "set or reset" do they mean toggle? You can do that with an xor.

Comment: @MatthewMellott... if the bit is `0` then make it `1`.just once.

Comment: @Krishna: If the bit is 0, make it 1; Else if the bit is 1, make it 0? That would be a toggle. If that is not what they were asking for them I'm confused.

Comment: @MatthewMellott... Not toggle. Let I have a number 32 . make the third bit set. this is the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In short, a branch instruction is something like:

If the result of the last operation was zero/non-zero/overflow/underflow/compared smaller/compared bigger/etc. (there are lots of different conditions that can be tested), then jump to that instruction over there, otherwise keep executing here.

Almost all CPUs have branch instructions, and the concept is more or less the same across them all. Branching means that the instructions the CPU executes contain a conditional jump. An either-or choice. Which could mean an `if`, a `for`-loop, `while`-loop, `switch`, `?:` or something that makes a decision based on a boolean.

One class of branches that people often forget are also short-circuiting boolean operators and possibly (but not necessarily on all CPUs) things that evaluate to truth values, so `int foo; ...; foo = !foo;` will be a branch on some CPUs, but not all (not on x86).

So to set a bit:

```
i |= (1 << bit);
```

Reset a bit:

```
i &= ~(1 << bit);
```

Toggle a bit:

```
i ^= (1 << bit);
```

No branches. I actually don't see how to make this so complicated to have to use a branch.

The reason why someone might want to worry about branches is branch prediction. See [this Stack Overflow answer on branch prediction failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array/11227902#11227902) for an excellent explanation of why that matters.

Answer (score 16):

Maybe they wanted you to show how to write a generic set/reset snippet without branches.

This could be accomplished with

```
value = (value & ~(1 << bit)) | (bitval << bit);
```

where `bit` is the bit position and `bitval` is 1 for set and 0 for reset.

Something even slightly more general is the following:

```
value = (value & ~(k1 << bit)) ^ (k2 << bit);
```

that implements several operations:

- `k1=0` and `k2=0` does nothing
- `k1=0` and `k2=1` toggles the bit
- `k1=1` and `k2=0` clears the bit
- `k1=1` and `k2=1` sets the bit

More generally with

```
value = (value & a) ^ x;
```

you can decide to change several bits of `value` at the same time by

- `aj=0`, `xj=0` → setting them to 0
- `aj=0`, `xj=1` → setting them to 1
- `aj=1`, `xj=0` → leaving them untouched
- `aj=1`, `xj=1` → flipping them

depending on the pre-computed constants `a` and `x` (`aj` and `xj` are the value of the j-th bit in the constants).

For example

```
value = (value & 0x0F) ^ 0x3C;
```

with a single operation will

```
- leave untouched bit 0 and 1
- flip bits 2 and 3
- set to 1 bits 4 and 5
- set to 0 all other bits
```